# What do two fingers up mean on roads in California?

Tags: driving, california

European driving in California here, some guy passed us on the right side on route 50 between Sacramento and Lake Tahoe (two lanes each way) and was very intently showing us this sign. What does it mean? What could we have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: You were in the left lane, and letting traffic pass you on the right?  Slower traffic should always keep in the right lane except to pass other traffic (or to turn left, if it's not a freeway), except in right-hand-drive countries where the opposite is done.

Comment: Were you driving on left lane?

Comment: I grew up in California and have never seen or heard of this gesture anywhere in the U.S.; we would need more information before we can guess. Was the person waving or wagging the fingers? What direction were the fingers pointed? The palm? Was the person smiling, scowling, or making any other kind of facial expression? A twist of the hand could be "a friendly salute," an insistent pointing could mean "pay attention to your surroundings," and so on.

Comment: I disagree. Although the rule _is_ to stay in right lane unless you’re passing someone, there are probably only three or four people in the whole United States that care to do so.

Comment: @Aganju That might be true that people don't obey the rule in all cases, but they should, and in some states (e.g. Oklahoma) you can get a large ticket if you don't do it.  And it will absolutely encourage driver gestures, even if it is legal, if you do do it.

Comment: @Aganju The exact statute [depends on the state](http://www.mit.edu/%7Ejfc/right.html), but in California [it is the law](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=21654) to yield to faster traffic, *even if* you are traveling at the posted speed limit.

Comment: @Aganju If you fail to yield to faster traffic while driving in the left lane, the faster car will not be happy.  The expectation is that you will get out of the way in all parts of the country that I have been.

Comment: @choster You're probably right. We were in the left lane, traveling a few mph above the speed limit already, and the guy who passed us was going at about ten more.

Comment: From a driver who has just passed you on the right, I would interpret *any* gesture as meaning "I am angry that you were in the left lane and traveling slower than I wanted to go."

Comment: Or he’s a Cub Scout leader and mistook you for one of the parents in his pack.  :-)

Comment: Someone has passed you on your right, and you don't know what have you done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think it is a standard sign, but I would understand it as a reminder that there are two lanes - did you swerve over the divider, making it ‘one lane’ (and annoying him)?

Comment: If they mean “peace,” “victory,” or “two,” the fingers will be separated, not touching as in the image.

Answer (score 5):

As a Californian, I disagree with the previous answer. I think two fingers is is pretty clearly a friendly "hello" wave (it might be accompanied by the word "peace"). In this case, he was likely either saying:

> "Yo! Sorry I'm passing you on the right!"

or, if he's being passive-aggressive:

> "I'm not happy that I have to pass you on the right, but I'll make a friendly-looking wave anyways so that I don't seem too mean... but, hopefully you take the hint and move over, ~expletive~!